# Why is there no output when I run this code with cheerio?

Tags: javascript, arrays, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to get all the gif links from https://giphy.com/search/test and put them into an array using request and cheerio.
When I run my code nothing happens. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

urls = [

];

    request("https://giphy.com/search/test", function(err, resp, body){
    if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $("a.giphy-gif css-d0ovzf", "#GridWithTV-sc-1hnvpyn eLOeIu").each(function(){
            var url = this.attr('href');
            urls.push(url)
            console.log(urls)
        })

    }
});
```

Comment: You should add debug prints to know where it is failing. You only do something when everything succeeds and nothing when anything fails. You need to debug this yourself more and then come back with a question we can help you with.

Comment: cheeio wont render the app like your browser. so its not much use. All the images your after is in the json, which you can extract with regex direct from body then parse it i.e `let matches = /gifs: (.*),/g.exec(body);
console.log(JSON.parse(matches[1]))` [example](https://runkit.com/lcherone/5ecada650a1005001ae201d5) but there is an API which you could also use https://developers.giphy.com/

Answer (score 0):

Converting an [excellent comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61991772/why-is-there-no-output-when-i-run-this-code-with-cheerio/74973622#comment109642501_61991772) to an answer, the data you get from an HTTP request is just the plain HTML. This website is a single page app which is mostly JS-driven. The selectors are built after the page loads and the browser executes JavaScript.

However, most of the data that goes onto the page is available in a JSON blob in the static HTML and can be extracted with a regex:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
require("util").inspect.defaultOptions.depth = null;

const url = "<Your URL>";

fetch(url)
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Error(res.statusText);
    }

    return res.text();
  })
  .then(html => {
    const match = html.match(/^ *gifs: (.*),$/m);
    console.log(JSON.parse(match[1]));
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

From here, it's a matter of grabbing the data you want, for example:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(match[1])
  .map(({title, url}) => ({title, url}));
console.log(data);
```